# Generics Type issue

Tags: java, generics

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrI = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList arrO = arrI; // Warning
/*  It is ok to add a String as it is an ArrayList of Objects
    but the JVM will know the real type, arrO is an arrayList of
    Integer... 
*/
arrO.add("Hello"); 
/*  How I can get a String in an ArrayList<Integer> ?? 
    Even if the compiler told me that I will get an Integer!
*/
System.out.println(arrI.get(0));
```

Anybody can explain what's happening here?

Comment: Did you read and understand the warning? The warning told you that by writing this code you are bypassing all the compile time type checks for arrI.

Comment: @DJClayworth ok, but the last line is really wierd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM doesn't know the real type, because generics are implemented via *type erasure*.

In terms of bytecode (and therefore runtime behaviour), your code is equivalent to:

```
ArrayList arrI = new ArrayList();
ArrayList arrO = arrI;
arrO.add("Hello"); 
System.out.println(arrI.get(0));
```

Answer (score 3):

Due to [`type erasure`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) generics doesn't exist at runtime. In practice that means your arraylist can carry any type of object. Generics is only a programmer conveniance which lets the compiler verify some of your code for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

At runtime the generics information is lost. It only prevents errors at compile time.

If you try arr1.add("Hello"); it will throw an error at compile time as arr1 has been declared as ArrayList but as arr0 can be assigned arr1 at any point in runtime - it has to allow it.